# PostMessage: How to post a message to a process that does not have a window?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi, dll

I am working with windows credential provider using a device that authenticates a user. Communication with the device is done on a separate thread.

I created and registered a credential provider `dll` that windows interfaces with. The `dll` creates a thread that authenticates the user and calls the credential provider. However, the call to the credential provider is currently on the thread that was created and not the main thread that windows `Logon/UI` is on. This is clearly going to cause threading problems.

The solution is to use `PostMessage` to post a message from the created thread to the `Logon/UI` thread. I've only used `PostMessage` with a windows gui application. How can I post a message from a thread to the windows `Logon/UI` process in my application?

Comment: You cannot. `PostMessage` requires a window. If your target does not have a window you can call [`PostThreadMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644946.aspx). However, if the target thread does not have a window it is likely that it doesn't have a message loop either, and will never even know that a message is in its queue. I'm not sure why you name DLLs in the final paragraph. DLLs are binary images, just like EXEs are. A DLL is not responsible for not having a GUI. This paragraph does not make sense.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks for the info. I'll research into `Logon/UI` to find out if it has an event loop. I suspect that it does.

Comment: Even if the target process runs a message loop, `PostThreadMessage` may be unreliable. As soon as the target process displays modal UI, using its own nested message loop, thread messages will be filtered and discarded. If you own both processes you can implement a more versatile and reliable infrastructure, e.g. using serialization and a named pipe transport channel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My initial reaction was the same: you cannot.

But it is not a complete answer: you do not have to have a full blown window, you just need a message pump. COM uses the same technique when running in a STA (single thread apartment). A STA will create a hidden window. This is the reason the local server main thread needs to implement a Windows message pump.

The message pump can be as simple as:

```
MSG msg;
while (GetMessage (&msg, 0, 0, 0))
   DispatchMessage (&msg);
```

COM does this to allow RPC between client and servers in different processes. You can do the same (google for COM STA, or read it on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680112%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

But you probably won't need to go down that way... 
As far as I understood, you own both threads (they are both in your codebase), and they run in the same process. You can use some shared memory + signaling approach (like global variables and Mutexes).

Comment: The solution was to use condition variable and wait until the thread was finish or i ran out of time. This answer help me a lot with that.